# how to get the changed color code from iris color picker

Tags: jquery

I want to use color picker to change the element of the color.
I chose iris color.

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/iris.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id='color-picker' value="#bada55" />
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#color-picker').iris();
  });
```

It's displays the color but I am not able to get the changed color. In the console itself the input value is not changing, but it changing in the browser.

my code is not working even the alert is not working

```
   $(function(){

       $("#color-picker").on("change", function(){
           alert($(this).val());
           var color = $(this).val();
           $.post("updatecolor.php", {color: color});
       });
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official documentation [here](http://automattic.github.io/Iris/), the correct way to catch the change event is as follows-

```
$('#color-picker').iris({
    change: function(event, ui) {
        // event = standard jQuery event, produced by whichever control was changed.
        // ui = standard jQuery UI object, with a color member containing a Color.js object

        // write your code here
    }
});
```

Avoid your custom change event and try this out.

Also, from the documentation-

> See [Color.js](https://github.com/Automattic/Color.js) documentation for what you can do with that `ui.color` object. In most cases, you’ll just want `ui.color.toString()` to produce a hex color string.